# Cadastro com popOver - Step by step Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Bom dia, estou com um problema na utilização da popOver, preciso fazer um cadastro do tipo step by step utilizando popOver no cadastro, mas quando tento fechar uma popOver e abrir outra, não estou conseguindo ele fecha a popOver que estou tentando abrir, segue abaixo o código.

```
let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopOverCadastroNome")
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
present(vc, animated: true, completion:{()->Void in
      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

O código da `completion` será executado assim que o VC for apresentado, então como vc chamou o `dismiss` na `completion` ela será dismissada assim que for apresentada.
Vc pode dar uma olhada na [documentação do método present](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621380-present) pra entender melhor